# Is there a hardware solution for two computers to share simultaneous access to a USB 2.0 memory stick (one R/W, the other just R)?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

A similar question was asked before: [Connect USB storage device to 2 computers at a time](https://superuser.com/questions/604911/connect-usb-storage-device-to-2-computers-at-a-time). However, it was ambiguous whether the asker wanted to achieve proper simultaneous access or would be satisfied with just a switch. In my case, it's the former.

Specifically, I have a Smart TV [set-top box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-top_box) that writes system logs to a USB 2.0 memory stick. It's a pain to have to constantly eject the stick and plug it into my Mac to read the logs, one test-run after another.

I'd prefer to keep the USB stick plugged into the set-top box at all times (with read-write access) whilst somehow allowing simultaneous read-only access from my Mac.

To be clear, there is no terminal access to this set-top box – writing logs to a USB stick is the only workflow available.

So is there a hardware-based solution to allow these two devices to share a simultaneous connection to the same USB 2.0 stick (one with R/W access, the other with just R access)? Thanks.

Comment: In order for USB to work there must be a USB Host and a USB device.  There are devices to switch between two hosts but I am not aware of any method that allows you to share a single device between two hosts simultaneously   There is a software solution but that won't be possible since you are dealing with a STB

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a hardware-based solution to allow these two devices to share a simultaneous connection to the same USB 2.0 stick (one with R/W access, the other with just R access)?

No, and even if there was a hypothetical solution at the USB level, you'd have logical issues with the filesystem "*changing under your feet*" which wouldn't work well at all.

Instead, I'd suggest a USB switch that would permit swapping the device between the two hosts without physically (un)plugging - instead you'd just press a button. It significantly improves the workflow in this sort of situation (I know from experience).

Comment: A switch gets me no further – I'm aiming for a solution where I can tail the logs at run-time, rather than making my existing batch process slightly less tedious. I do accept that this may not technically be possible, but am keeping the question open in case there's a little-known solution out there.

Comment: @JamieBirch That ain't going to happen. The USB protocol (hardware and software) simply has no provisions for this. There exist hardware USB bus analyzers to debug what is happening between host (TV) and device (stick), but these would NOT provide normal access to the stick at filesystem level. Not even readonly.

Comment: "_I'm aiming for a solution where I can tail the logs at run-time_" ... if you're comfortable with it, you could set up a Raspberry Pi or similar as a USB gadget. A MSC gadget won't work for similar "_filesystem changing underfoot_" reasons, but you could try periodically remounting the filesystem... might also be worth seeing if the STB will write logs to PTP devices, which may permit real-time monitoring...