# Shared USB drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb

I’m looking for a way to share an USB flash drive between two units ,the devices being a raspberry pi and a blackmagic atem mini pro switcher.

I know that two devices can’t access a usb drive at the same time , but my use case is to have each device accessing the drive at different times , the device not accessing the drive doesn’t even need to see it as a physical device. My thinking is to have a physical switch between two modes. When in “video capture” the atem mini has access to the drive and will output hdmi to a screen . When in “video playback” the pi should have access to the disc and the screen .
I don’t think the atem mini will mount anything other than a usb disk so the switch needs to be a physical switch just passing through the signal .
Anyone has any suggestions of such a switch? Or another way of solving my problem with recording and reading from same device?

Cheers

Comment: Don't know if the devices mentioned are still on the market, but here's a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/604911/connect-usb-storage-device-to-2-computers-at-a-time

Comment: I also get the impression that device of yours is able to use network drives (i.e. samba), then you can use an actual HDD on a host device and just share it. Higher write speeds and easier access that way.

Comment: I saw the first thread but i don’t think it’s applicable in my case. That thread relates having access to the drive at the same time. My use case is accessing at different time , more like pulling the cable from one device and plugging into the other

Comment: Aha, did not see that samba option. Need to check that, did you find any information about that?

Comment: I may have misread. This post from 2020 flat out says 'no': https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=116838

Comment: considering this thing receives firmware updates though, and there should be nothing physically in the way of making that possible, I would definitely do a feature request. Bit strange that they sell expensive hardware, then make you rely on a flimsy USB drive rather than just connect to the network.

Comment: Also, being able to access a drive at the same time does not stop you from accessing it at different times :)

Comment: I also noticed this post btw: https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=112323 - I've not gotten to the end of it, but if you CAN stream to the network, you can also capture that stream somewhere else for recording and (later) playback. Might require some setting up, but this would also bypass USB drives completely :)